# Plotting a 3D surface in Mathematica: NIntegrate Evaluates to Non-Numerical Values, How Can I Correct This?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to run [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSOR9.png) in Mathematica 10, but I don't know how to deal with the error that I receive when trying to plot the surface that I define. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5ma5.png) is what I'm trying to run, followed by the error I receive:

```
In[1]: s[y_] = ceiling[y*(1 - UnitStep[-y])]

Out[1]: ceiling[y (1 - UnitStep[-y])]

In[2]: f[t_] = t^2

Out[2]: t^2

In[3]: (Integrate \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(x\)]\(\((\((x - 
         t)\)^\((\(-1\) - y - 
         ceiling[y*\((1 - UnitStep[\(-y\)])\)])\))\)*
     D[f[t], {t, 
       ceiling[y*\((1 - UnitStep[\(-y\)])\)]}] \[DifferentialD]t\)\))/
 Gamma[ceiling[y*(1 - UnitStep[-y])] - y]

Out[3]: (Integrate \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(x\)]\(\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-t\) + x)\), \(\(-1\) - y - 
      ceiling[y\ \((1 - UnitStep[\(-y\)])\)]\)]\ \*
SuperscriptBox["Power", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"ceiling", "[", 
RowBox[{"y", " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "-", 
RowBox[{"UnitStep", "[", 
RowBox[{"-", "y"}], "]"}]}], ")"}]}], "]"}], ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None][t, 2]\) \[DifferentialD]t\)\))/Gamma[-y + 
  ceiling[y (1 - UnitStep[-y])]]

In[4]: Plot3D[(Integrate \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(x\)]\(\((\((x - 
          t)\)^\((\(-1\) - y - 
          ceiling[y*\((1 - UnitStep[\(-y\)])\)])\))\)*
      D[f[t], {t, 
        ceiling[y*\((1 - 
            UnitStep[\(-y\)])\)]}] \[DifferentialD]t\)\))/
  Gamma[ceiling[y*(1 - UnitStep[-y])] - y], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -2, 2}]

Out[4] NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (-5.99914-t)^(0.999714 -ceiling[0.]) (Power^(ceiling[0.],0))[t,2] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,-5.99914}}. >>

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (-5.99914-t)^(0.999714 -ceiling[0.]) (Power^(ceiling[0.],0))[t,2] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,-5.99914}}. >>

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (-5.99914-t)^(0.999714 -ceiling[0.]) (Power^(ceiling[0.],0))[t,2] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,-5.99914}}. >>

General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumr will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

\!\(\*
Graphics3DBox[{},
Axes->True,
AxesLabel->{None, None, None},
BoxRatios->{1, 1, 0.4},
DisplayFunction->Identity,
FaceGridsStyle->Automatic,
Method->{"DefaultBoundaryStyle" -> Directive[
GrayLevel[0.3]], "RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
PlotRange->{{-6, 6}, {-2, 2}, {0., 0.}},
PlotRangePadding->{
Scaled[0.02], 
Scaled[0.02], 
Scaled[0.02]},
Ticks->{Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}]\)
```

Can anybody tell me how exactly I can fix my code so that I can plot the surface that I am trying to plot? Any help at all would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Mathematica is case sensitive. I believe you need to change ceiling to `Ceiling`. Next you are using both Integrate and it doesn't appear that you have `Integrate[expression,variable]` or `Integrate[expression,{variable,lower,upper}]`. Then inside that you are using the little graphic for integration. Do you really mean to have an integration inside another integration? Next you have `D[f[t], {t, ceiling[y*(1-UnitStep[-y])]}] ` Do you really mean that is what you want? Next you have `Power` used in a very odd way. Can you really simply explain what you want without the Mathematica confusion?

Comment: @Bill Thanks and Hello, I've changed the double integration with the incorrect syntax to single, definite integration. Additionally, I changed the case of the "c" in "ceiling" to be capital. However, yes, I actually do want to take the ceiling[y*(1-UnitStep[-y])] th-order derivative of the function f(x), the idea behind this is that ceiling[y*(1-UnitStep[-y])] always outputs a non-negative integer. I'm not sure what you mean about my use of Power. Here is what I run and the error that I get now, which is still the same issue: link.

Comment: update the question to reflect those fixes.

Comment: IF you can either post a working link to your latest notebook or you 'scrape-n-paste' your expression off the screen and edit that into your original code block then there should be no "SuperscriptBox", no "RowBox", just roughly the same text that you see on the screen. That should help a lot. You cab tell if it worked if you can submit the changes after editing, scrape the code off the screen, paste it into Mathematica, <shift><enter> and see exactly the same results that you had previously. f[t_]:=t^2;D[f[t], {t,Ceiling[y*(1-UnitStep[-y])]}]<shift><enter> shows my confusion about your Power